# How can I achive code metrics for C# code in Jenkins?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, jenkins, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

How can I achieve code metrics for C# code in Jenkins, for example [Cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CCM+Plugin) for Cyclomatic complexity in .NET available.
Have you tried it?